# How to allow user to input phone number of 9 or 10 digit using bootstrap input mask?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Just now I am using input mask of bootstrap to allow user input their phone number. I defined 10 digits for input the phone number (999-999-9999). It's fine if I input with 10 digits, but if I wish to input with only 9 digits, this option is not allow me to do that.

Here is my input box:

```
<input type="text" name="phone1" id="phone1" class="form-control" data-mask="999-999-9999">
```

What I want is to allow user to input weather 9 or 10 digits as they wish.
Really appreciate for any helps :)

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe you need to use JQuery for that.  Something like On-the-fly mask change

Comment: @Mark I just found the solution after asking the question. It was like a very easy. just change (999-999-9999)->(999-999-999?9). It's work great.

Comment: @LinaTum this is assuming he is using Jasny Bootstrap?

Comment: Guess I really do learn something new everyday